# DropShadow on frame WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using this code to get a dropshadow effect on my frame :

```
 <Frame x:Name="MenuItem" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="439" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="262" Margin="0,130,0,0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden">
        <Frame.BitmapEffect>
            <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="Black" Direction="50"
                ShadowDepth="3" Softness="100" />
            </Frame.BitmapEffect>
    </Frame>
```

The produced result is this :[image: 01]

But i want to achieve this : [image: image 2]

What changes should i make ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set

```
Background="White"
```

to your `Frame`, as the shadow is applied to the texture, so you'll see it everywhere there's transparency inside your control. Also note that `DropShadowBitmapEffect` is obsolete, you should use `DropShadowEffect` instead.